# Bash Script to process irregular text, count occurrences, cut at a threshold

Tags: bash, shell, text, scripting, nlp

I have a large sample of text that is pretty irregular and I'd like to tokenize it to single words, and count occurrences of each words, and have an output where occurrence > threshold_value

```
if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
        echo 'Usage <file> <output_file> <threshold>'
        exit 1
fi

clean_and_rank () {
    tr -dc [:graph:][:cntrl:][:space:] < $1 \
    | tr -d [:punct:] \
    | tr -s ' ' \
    | tr ' ' '\n' \
    | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' \
    | grep -v '^$' \
    | sort \
    | uniq -c \
    | sort -nr
}

cut_below_threshold () {
        $THRESHOLD=$1
        awk '$1 > '$THRESHOLD' { print $1, $2 }'
}

clean_and_rank $1 \
| cut_below_threshold $3
| sort -nr > $2
```

but for some reason I'm running into trouble with the cut_below_threshold() function --

Also once I get this done, I want to be able to compare it to another sample (my data is 2 samples of several rows of labeled text snippets and I want to score words independently for prevalence in sample A/sample B)

Is there a better way to go about this? Ultimately, I'm looking for insights along the lines of "$WORD is in sample 1 1000 times, out of 100000 total words, it is in sample 2 100 times out of 10000 words"

Comment: In `bash` you don't initialize a variable with `$`. `$THRESHOLD=$1` should be `THRESHOLD=$1`

Comment: And you know that you can do `wordCount=$(wc -w <file)` to get your current file count? Good question! Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are able to get statistics for two text files in the following format:

```
$ cat a.txt
5 word1
3 word2
1 word3
$ cat b.txt
4 word1
3 word2
1 word4
```

Then this script does the job of comparison:

```
#!/bin/sh
# the 1st argument passed to the script, the 1st file to compare (statistics for sample A)
STATA=$1
# the 2nd argument -- the 2nd file (statistics for sample B)
STATB=$2
# concatenate both files and pipe it to the next command
cat ${STATA} ${STATB} |
# call awk; -v is awk option to set a variable
# n1=$() variable n1 gets its value from the output of the command in ()
# wc -l <file counts number of lines in the file
# ' starts awk script
awk -v n1=$(wc -l <${STATA}) '
# (){} means when condition in () is true, execute statement in {}
# NR is number of records processed thus far (usually this is number of lines)
# (NR <= n1) essentially means 'reading statistics file for sample A'
# {1; 2} two statements
# wa += $1 add value of the first field to the wa variable
# each line is splitted by a field separator (space or tab by default) into several fields:
# $1 is the 1st field, $2 is the 2nd, $NF is the last one, $0 is a whole line
# $1 in this case is number of occurrences of a word 
# awk variables have zero default value; no need to specify them explicitly
# cnta[] is an associative array -- index is a string (the word in this case)
# $2 in this case is the word
(NR <= n1){wa += $1; cnta[$2] = $1}
# the same for statistics for sample B
(NR  > n1){wb += $1; cntb[$2] = $1}
# END{} to execute statements after there's no input left
END {
  print "nof words in sample A = " wa;
  print "nof words in sample B = " wb;
  # standard printf to output a table header
  printf "%-15s %5s %8s %5s %8s\n", "word", "cntA", "freqA", "cntB", "freqB";
  # iterate over each element (the word) in the count array A
  for (w in cnta){
    # check that the word is present in the count array B
    if (cntb[w] > 0) {
      # output statistics in a table form
      printf "%-15s %5d %8.6f %5d %8.6f\n", w, cnta[w], cnta[w] / wa, cntb[w], cntb[w]/wb
    }
  }
}
'
```

Test run:

```
$ ./compare.sh a.txt b.txt
nof words in sample A = 9
nof words in sample B = 8
word             cntA    freqA  cntB    freqB
word1               5 0.555556     4 0.500000
word2               3 0.333333     3 0.375000
```

Comment: This looks like it will work awesomely, and I'll sort of explore on my own how to cut it based on the values it outputs.

But since I'm relatively new to bash scripting, could you maybe give me a tl;dr of what exactly that code is doing, or even just direct me to some relevant guides on the subject?

I know I could check out the manual for awk, but I still rely pretty heavily on plain text explanations

Comment: This script has a number of concepts, I tried to explain them. For details see [here](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_toc.html). Please don't forget to accept the answer if that works :)

Comment: Incredibly helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let bash do most of your work with associative arrays.  This is not a rigorous example, that is left as an exercise for you:

```
declare -A ct

exec 3< file
while IFS= read -u3 line ; do
   set -- $line
   for tkn ; do
      cct=${ct[$tkn]}
      ct[$tkn]=$(( ${cct:-0} + 1 ))
   done
done

for tkn in ${!ct[*]}
do echo $tkn ${ct[$tkn]} ; done
```